# How do I deserialize from a file, that I saved List<> Objects to?

Tags: java, list, deserialization

EDIT: Did any of you ever deserialize a List as a whole? Because whenever I try this code with a simple object that is no List it works. It seems like deserialization and casting onto a List just doesn't work in general.

How do I deserialize a List from a file? This is some example code I did for this (I know this is not working, I just wrote it to make my idea clear) :

```
public List<FileRead> loadList(File file) {
    List<FileRead> feeds = new ArrayList<FileRead>();

    try (ObjectInputStream ois = 
            new ObjectInputStream(
                    new FileInputStream(file))){
        feeds = (List<FileRead>) ois.readObject();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return feeds;
}
```

Please have mercy on me, I'm really a starter and need this for my class.
Edit: Here is the code for the serialization (changed it up to serializing the whole list, doesn't work though):

```
public void saveList(List<FileRead> fRead, File saveFile) {     
        try (ObjectOutputStream oos =
            new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(saveFile))){
            oos.writeObject(fRead);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: Change the code which serializes the objects. Instead, serialize the whole list, so that you can use the code you posted to... deserialize the whole list.

Comment: Without seeing the code that serializes the objects, we cannot tell you how to deserialize them. But probably simply call `ois.readObject()` in a loop until the stream reaches EOF. What JB Nizet said: If you want to deserialize a list, you must serialize a list. If you want to serialize objects, you must deserialize objects.

Comment: I did serialize the list as a whole but for some reason this deserialization code is not working :/

Comment: @javaPabla post your code. It's easier to debug code when you don't have to imagine what it could be.

Comment: Hm. Does your class FileRead implement serializable? Besides that, your code looks okay. Maybe try using a simple list of String for further testing.

Comment: Yup, it implements Serializable. Whenever I did code like this with a "normal" self defined class that wasn't a list, there was no problem. I figured that deserialization seemingly doesn't work with a list, or do any of you have other experiences?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I deserialize a List from a file? I serialized the items of a List to a file via a for-each-loop, but I don't know how to do it the other way around.

You do that: by doing **symmetric** operations.

Either you do:

- serialize the **list** object as a whole, then you can use your above code to read back that whole list **or**
- if you want to keep your current serialization code, then you need to: keep reading objects until you get EOF, or more "robust": you serialize the number of elements in the list, and then that number of elements. Then your read code can first read the number, and then knows how many follow on reads to do.

But as said: the simple solution is: serialize and de-serialize the whole list.

Comment: I've tried the first, the problem is it's not working and I have no idea why.. During serialization I serialized the list as a whole, like you said but when I deserialize I just get the EOFException

Comment: @javaPabla Well, then edit your question and show us a  [mcve] for **serialization**. We cant tell you why the write part doesnt work, when you dont share it with us.

Answer (score 0):

Native Java Serialization is an old way of doing that. It may work but has some problems, such as that it is not guaranteed to be backwards compatible. Much more acceptable way today is to serialize your objects to JSON (or XML if you need your file to be more readable for human eyes). Here are some resources that will get you started.
For JSON serialization see this article: [Intro to the Jackson ObjectMapper](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial), For XML serialization see this one: [XML Serialization and Deserialization with Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-xml-serialization-and-deserialization), and also see javadoc for [ObjectMapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) class. All recomendations work with Jackson JSON also known as Fast XML library - de-facto standard for working with JSON/XML serialization